# hp xw4200 fan speed

Tags: power-management, fan

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my old HP xw4200 workstation (p4 3.4 GHz, 3 GB of RAM, Ati FireGL 5200). The install worked without any issue and the system seems responsive.

The problem is that the cpu fan is spinning at maximum speed (and it's very loud). I supose some kind of power management is not working.

Any idea about how to make it quiet?

Regards

Pit